# How to retrieve facebook user's ads account id?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-ads-api

In my app I want to create Facebook ads on behalf of a user. How do I discover via API if he has a FB Ads account and what's his Ads account id?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Provided your app has access to the [Ads API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ads-api/) and you have the `ads_management` [Permission](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/login/extended-permissions/) you can retrieve the list of Advertising Accounts with a call to `/<USER ID>/adaccounts`

The response is an array of `adaccount` objects, documented here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ads-api/adaccount/

Comment: This answer predates the introduction of ads_read in late 2013 - the current docs for ads api access can be found here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/access

Answer (score 5):

You can use the facebook graph explorer to discorever this informations. you must specify the fields to pass to the facebook graph explorer. Example :

https://graph.facebook.com/{user_id}?fields=id,name,adaccounts

Also you can find using this http://rubygems.org/gems/zuck to retrieve all adaccounts/ads/account_id that specific user, just remember that you must have sufficient permissions to read this information and also need a token that has not expired .